# How to align an Angular component horizontally and vertically in a div

Tags: html, angular, flexbox

Please could I as for help with the following:

I have the following HTML to make a fullscreen brown DIV:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: brown;">
<app-text-cloner style="display: flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;"></app-text-cloner>
```

The HTML of the app-text-cloner is:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" spellcheck="false" [(ngModel)]="m_text1">
```

<input type="tex2" id="text2" name="text2" spellcheck="false" [(ngModel)]="m_text1">

I was hoping that this would produce a vertically and horizontally centered result, instead it's only horizontally centered:[image]

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Try to give the div a height of 100vh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I think what you need is to set a full height in the container i.e., `height: 100%;`. Try out:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: brown;">
<app-text-cloner style="display: flex; height:100%; justify-content:center; align-items:center;"></app-text-cloner>
```